# bootstrap change tab by url parameter and set anchor not working firefox

Tags: url, parameters, tabs, anchor, panel

i am doing tab panel and anchor(eg html?tab=profile#f1) in bootstrap

Please run http://www.timothyhui.com/test/boom/hash_tab/ver2/go.html

i made some examples with parameter in one page, when user click one of example and go to another page.
Then that page gets parameters and anchor, then the tab will be changed and anchor jumps.

i have tested chrome and ie9 to edge are fine, however in firefox(tab=profile#p1 and tab=profile#p2), it's not working
please kindly help. i have tried to search any method in interent, but i have no any ideas.

Comment: tab=profile#p1
tab=profile is change tab
#p1 is anchor in profile tab
chrome and ie are fine, but firefox can't jump to #p1.
please go the link as below and click "tab=profile#p1", "tab=profile#p2" or "tab=messages&pane=m13#m2"
Please run http://www.timothyhui.com/test/boom/hash_tab/ver2/go.html

Thanks for help

Comment: tab=profile#p1,
tab=profile is change tab,
#p1 is anchor in profile tab,
chrome and ie are fine, but firefox can't jump to #p1.
please go the link as below and click "tab=profile#p1", "tab=profile#p2" or "tab=messages&pane=m13#m2"
Please run http://www.timothyhui.com/test/boom/hash_tab/ver2/go.html

Thanks for help